# Creating a numerically ascending list of links on a spreadsheet whilst showing a numerically ascending list of names in the column

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I've looked for some other answers to this but can't quite seem to find one that I understand and can make work.

I have a spreadsheet.

In `Column A` I want a list of entries that go `BA 0001` up to `BA 0200`

Each of those entries should be a link that would match the number, so:
`AE/Live/BA 0001.xlsx` through to `AE/Live/BA 0200.xlsx`.

Is there a quick way of doing this? Currently I'm doing it by hand for each link which takes far too long. I have other sheets which go up to 1,000, so this is something I'm very keen to figure out!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In column A put `AE/Live/BA`

In column B put `0001`

In column C put `.xlsx`

In column D put `=A&B&C`

The ampersand symbols `&` concatenate the cells.

Then fill down to make the list.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your time.

I've got the above working, but I notice that it shows it up as the link path, rather than 'BA0001', 'BA0001' etc. Any idea how I would then make it hide the path behind the entry name for neatness and to comply with the standard formats we use?

Comment: In column E put `=HYPERLINK(d1,"BA0001")`

Comment: Well would you look at that. So I can just hide the first four columns, everything works a charm. Thank you very much, that's made my life so much easier.